# Filtering pyspark dataframe if text column includes words in specified list

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've seen questions posted here that are similar to mine, but I'm still getting errors in my code when trying some accepted answers.  I have a dataframe with three columns--created _at, text, and words (which is just tokenized version of text).  See below:

[image]

Now, I have a list of companies `['Starbucks', 'Nvidia', 'IBM', 'Dell']`, and I only want to keep the rows where the text includes those words above.

I've tried a few things, but with no success:

```
small_DF.filter(lambda x: any(word in x.text for word in test_list))
```

Returns : TypeError: condition should be string or Column

I tried creating a function and using `foreach()`:

```
def filters(line):
   return(any(word in line for word in test_list))
df = df.foreach(filters)
```

That turns df into 'Nonetype'

And the last one I tried:

```
df = df.filter((col("text").isin(test_list))
```

This returns an empty dataframe, which is nice as I get no error, but obviously not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `filter` isnt working becuase it expects a boolean output from lambda function and `isin` just compares with column. You are trying to compare list of words to list of words. Here is something that I tried can give you some direction -

```
# prepare some test data ==> 

words = [x.lower() for x in ['starbucks', 'Nvidia', 'IBM', 'Dell']]
data = [['i love Starbucks'],['dell laptops rocks'],['help me I am stuck!']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF('text')


from pyspark.sql.types import *

def intersect(row):
    # convert each word in lowecase
    row = [x.lower() for x in row.split()]
    return True if set(row).intersection(set(words)) else False


filterUDF = udf(intersect,BooleanType())
df.where(filterUDF(df.text)).show()
```

output :

```
+------------------+
|              text|
+------------------+
|  i love Starbucks|
|dell laptops rocks|
+------------------+
```

Comment: I tried the UDF you wrote above on my dataframe, replacing df.where and df.text with my data; however, I'm getting the error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.

For the intersect function, technically your passing in a column (df.text) as the parameter, right?  Is the error because it's not iterating row by row?

Comment: Does your column text has nulls in it, that may explain NoneType error. You will have to handle that in udf as ` if row in None return False` . For intersect row values i.e. `i love Starbucks`. It will be probably helpful if you post what you have tried along with sample data. Image of data isnt very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Your `.filter` returns an error because it is the sql filter function (expecting a `BooleanType()` column) on dataframes not the filter function on RDDs. If you want to use the RDD one, just add `.rdd`:

```py
small_DF.rdd.filter(lambda x: any(word in x.text for word in test_list))
```

You don't have to use a UDF, you can use regular expressions in pyspark with `.rlike` on your column `"text"`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

words = [x.lower() for x in ['starbucks', 'Nvidia', 'IBM', 'Dell']]
data = [['i love Starbucks'],['dell laptops rocks'],['help me I am stuck!']]
df = hc.createDataFrame(data).toDF('text')
df.filter(psf.lower(df.text).rlike('|'.join(words)))
```